# Node.js 3rd party REST API call

Tags: node.js, api, rest, request

Im using nodejs to make a call to a 3rd party API. My code code returns the correct data for an `id` that I'm passing in my backend. When I run my app, to retrieve the data I go to `localhost:5000/api/Dls`.

> My code

```
  app.get("/api/Dls", (req, res) => {
    const response = {
      success: false
    };
    if (req.user && Authorized.myToken) {
      response.success = true;
      response.data = {};
      response.data.user = req.user;
      const id = response.data.user.sub;
      var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://someApi/byId/' + 'id',
        headers:
        {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer' + ' ' + Authorized.myToken
        }
      };
      request(options, function (error, response, body){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }
        const data = response.body;
        const userDls = JSON.parse(data)
        return res.json(userDls);

      });
    }
  });
```

Now I'm trying to do something like this `localhost:5000/api/Dls/1234` instead of using a hard coded `id` in the backend

I attempted doing the following but when I enter a valid `id` in the url (ex. `localhost:5000/api/Dls/1234`) I get this `""`, any idea to what I should be doing?

```
  app.get("/api/Dls/:id", (req, res) => {
        const response = {
          success: false
        };
        if (Authorized.myToken) {
          response.success = true;
          var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://someApi/byId/',
            headers:
            {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              Authorization: 'Bearer' + ' ' + Authorized.myToken
            }
          };
          request(options, function (error, response, body){
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
              return;
            }
            const data = response.body;
            const userDls = JSON.parse(data)
            return res.json(userDls);

          });
        }
      });
```

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the route `id` to the api.

```
response.success = true;
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://someApi/byId/' + req.params.id,
  headers:{
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer' + ' ' + Authorized.myToken
  }
};
```